# Field With DLookup Not Updating On Certain Machine

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 form where the value of a field is determined by a DLookup using a value in a combobox. Here's the control source for the misbehaving text box:
`=DLookUp("companyname","dbo_company","companyid = '" & [Companyid] & "'")` where `[Companyid]` is the combobox in the form.

The database itself is stored in MSSQL. When loading a record the text box with the DLookup remains empty until I click on the text box to force it to update. There doesn't appear to be any problem accessing the database, as other fields in the form are being filled fine (including the combobox with the companyid).

Strangely, if I take this Access project and open it on another computer, the text box with the DLookup will load and display the information immediately upon loading a record. This would seem to indicate a configuration issue specific to my computer, but I don't see where such a configuration option would be. Both computers I'm running this on are using Access 2010. There is no code in the "events" handlers, and I'm running the exact same file on both computers (opening over Windows file share). I've already tried doing a "compact and repair", but that didn't change anything.

This also happens when selecting a value in the combobox - the text box will remain empty on one computer, but will update with the DLookup on another computer.

Why would a DLookup run immediately on one computer, but wait until "GotFocus" on another computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like this is a bug within Access itself. The issue appears to be some kind of interaction between the Windows Update service and MS Access. When updates get published on patch Tuesday, it causes the Access engine to go wonky. The short-term fix is to restart the computer. You can read more about this in 
[this lengthy thread on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1701369c-02b4-4f43-abe7-03b099b4d517/access-2010-form-fields-not-calculating-until-clicked?forum=accessdev)

The long-term fix is to apply [KB2899528](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2899528) (Access 2010) or [KB2956176](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2956176) (Access 2013). However, note that [KB2965300](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2965300) will overwrite and reintroduce the issue fixed by KB'528 for Access 2010. KB'300 is automatically applied by Windows Update, and now I can't seem to reapply KB'528, so I may be stuck with restarting the server every month.